# How to add a file to a particular branch in git?

Tags: git, cg

I am doing some sample test with git, before i add my actual stuff.

Here is what i do:

```
enter code here
1) Create an empty git repository

$ mkdir git_trial2
$ cd git_trial2
$ git init (Creates a .git directory inside this)
$ cg-branch-add branch1 (Create a branch1 inside this git)
$ touch File1
$ echo "This is a test" >> File1
```

Now i want to add File1 to branch1. How to do this?

Comment: Did i do that? Ohh mistake. But why did u mark it as close? Better don't answer that is ok.

Comment: I didn't vote for a close, someone else did..

Comment: Stop using cogito. It's obsolete and deprecated since 2006. I recommend you learn git basics instead, i.e. "git add", "git commit", "git branch", "git checkout" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just

```
git checkout branch1
git add File1
git commit -am "added File1"
git checkout other_branch
```

and File1 will only be in branch1

Comment: What happens if more than one branch is checked out? And we repeat the same as your commands?

Comment: then you would have two or more branches with the same file added, and that would probably result in a conflict when trying to merge them..

Comment: Is there any way to run the same command using `cg` cogito? Like cg-add?

Comment: Wait !! I get an error with the command!! `error: pathspec 'branch1' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Did you forget to 'git add'?`

Comment: this means you do not have a local branch called `branch1`... Is it possible that cg-branch-add only creates a remote branch? In that case you have to fetch that bracnh first. Or else just use `git branch branch1` to create a local branch.

Comment: But ls shows it: `$cg-branch-ls ---> branch1 /home/king/git_trial2`

Comment: don't have cg here so I cannot test it, but wat is the output of `git branch` ? You do get that error upon the checkout command, right?

Comment: $ git branch branch1 ------> fatal: Not a valid branch point: 'master'.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1009/discussion-between-stijn-and-kingsmasher1)

Answer (score 1):

Well we really need to know what your mysterious `cg-branch-add` command does, but assuming that it just adds a branch with `git branch` then you will need to start by switching to that branch:

```
git checkout branch1
```

then add the file:

```
git add File1
```

and commit it:

```
git commit
```

Comment: It is not mysterious, and it is not my command..i think you have missed "cg" or cogito or need to knwo about it.

Comment: I didn't miss anything - you didn't mention cogito anywhere in your question and I had no idea what your `cg` tag was for.

Comment: If the tag is there, then it means the question is somewhere related to that tag.